# Phonegap: How to add the plugin(such as FileSystem) to the blackberry10?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-10

Currently, I want to use the function requestFileSystem with blackberry10 in phonegap, could anyone help me to add this plugin or any other ways could be used?

Hope some one could help me. Thanks in advance.

Thanks & Regards
Azury

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is solved.

I run the command:
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git
before I add the platforms.

after add this plugin I create the platform, the plugin will be added into the new platform.